# Smtp status codes numeric and numeric dotted codes meanings

Tags: smtp, smtpclient

I'm new to smtp.
Sometimes I receive from severs headers like the following:
smtp; 550 5.1.1

Now I would like to understand the code, but Iack some specific terms to find out documentation.

How are called the first class of codes, (the ones composed by three digits) ?

How are called the second class ones, the ones composed by dots and digit?

Where Can I find specific docs for them, or chapter of smtp protocol referencing them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reply code and status code.
EG. 550 -> reply code 5.1.1 -> status code

This resource is quite explaining as well: 
https://support.google.com/a/answer/3221692?hl=en